# Need prompt for credentials from computer outside domain in a domain network

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain, network-share, credentials

I have a computer (Com1) which is connected to a network that is part of a domain (Dom1). On my Windows 2008 R2 server (Serv1), which is a part of the domain, I have a share called Program. The share is set up so that every user that is registered in and connected to the domain will have direct access when entering \Serv1\Program.

However, Com1 is not a part of the domain yet, but it still needs access to the share. How can I set up the share so that it will prompt for credentials when trying to access the share from outside the domain?

As things are now, I just get an "Access is denied" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use the command line to map a drive and provide domain credentials for it.

```
net use z: \\server.domain.com\programs password /user:domain\username
```

Not sure if this is what you are looking for though.

Comment: Yes. After seeing your post I used Map Network Drive and specified different credentials. It worked. Thank you.